# How to print a full stop after every iteration/sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm printing out a simple code:

```
favorite_places={'john':['serbia','bulgaria','israel'],
                 'adam':['russia','london','spain'],
                'eden':['turkey','california','london']}
for name,places in favorite_places.items():
    print("\n"+ name.title()+"'s favorite places are:" , end=' ')
    for place in places:
        print( place.title()+"",end=' ')
```

With the folowing output:

```
John's favorite places are: Serbia Bulgaria Israel 
Adam's favorite places are: Russia London Spain 
Eden's favorite places are: Turkey California London
```

What I would like to do it print a full stop after every sentence. So that my output looks like this:

```
John's favorite places are: Serbia Bulgaria Israel.
Adam's favorite places are: Russia London Spain.
Eden's favorite places are: Turkey California London.
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 1 of following 2 solutions:

Like:

1. A simple solution for this would be:

```
for name,places in favorite_places.items():
    places=[i.title() for i in places]
    print(name.title()+"'s favorite places are: "+" ".join(places),end="")
    print(".")
```

2. 

```
for name,places in favorite_places.items():
        print("\n"+ name.title()+"'s favorite places are:" , end=' ')
        for i,place in enumerate(places):
            if(i!=len(places)-1):
                print( place.title()+"",end=' ')
            else:
                print( place.title()+"",end='')
        print('.',end="")
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify the for loop like this:

```
for name,places in favorite_places.items():
    print("\n"+ name.title()+"'s favorite places are:" , end='')
    for place in places:
        print( " " + place.title(),end='')
    print(".")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
favorite_places={'john':['serbia','bulgaria','israel'],
                 'adam':['russia','london','spain'],
                'eden':['turkey','california','london']}
for name,places in favorite_places.items():
    print("\n"+ name.title()+"'s favorite places are:" , end=' ')
    for place in places:
        print( place.title()+"",end=' ')
    print("",end=".")
```

you only have to print the `print("",end=".")` before starting `places` for loop

Answer (score 1):

This is lot easier to understand:

```
favorite_places={'john':['serbia','bulgaria','israel'],
                 'adam':['russia','london','spain'],
                'eden':['turkey','california','london']}
for name,places in favorite_places.items():
    print("\n"+ name+"'s favorite places are:" ,' '.join(places), end='.')
```

The `' '.join(places)` will convert the list `places` into a string separated by a space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string format and join function.

```
favorite_places = {'john': ['serbia', 'bulgaria', 'israel'],
                   'adam': ['russia', 'london', 'spain'],
                   'eden': ['turkey', 'california', 'london']}
    
for name, places in favorite_places.items():
    print("\n {}'s favorite places are: {}.".format(name.title(), " ".join(places)), end=' ')
```